Powershell : ZipFile created but not able to maintain the folder structure
using namespace System.IO
using namespace System.IO.Compression

function Compress-CompatibleArchive {
    param (
        [String[]] $Path,
        [String] $DestinationPath,
        [ValidateSet("Fastest", "NoCompression", "Optimal", "Maximum")]
        [String] $CompressionLevel
    )
    ValidatePaths($Path)
    ValidateDestinationPath($DestinationPath)
    $outputStream = [FileStream]::new($DestinationPath, [FileMode]::Create, [FileAccess]::Write)
    $archive = [Compression.ZipArchive]::new($outputStream, [Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Create)

    if ("Fastest" -eq $CompressionLevel) {
        $level = [CompressionLevel]::Fastest
    } elseif ("Optimal" -eq $CompressionLevel) {
        $level = [CompressionLevel]::Optimal
    } elseif ("Maximum" -eq $CompressionLevel) {
        $level = [CompressionLevel]::SmallestSize
    } else {
        $level = [CompressionLevel]::NoCompression
    }
    foreach ($file in $Path) {
        $fileName = [Path]::GetFileName($file)
        $entry = $archive.CreateEntry($fileName, $level)
        $entryStream = $entry.Open()
        $inputStream = [FileStream]::new($file, [FileMode]::Open, [FileAccess]::Read)
        $inputStream.CopyTo($entryStream)
        $inputStream.Dispose()
        $entryStream.Dispose()
    }

    $archive.Dispose()
    $outputStream.Dispose()
}

function ValidatePaths([String[]] $paths) { 
    foreach ($f in $paths) { 
        $fi = [FileInfo]::new($f)
        if ($fi.Exists) { 
            continue
        } 
        
        throw [FileNotFoundException] "File not found ($f)"
    }
}

function ValidateDestinationPath { 
    param (
        [String] $destinationPath
    ) 
    
    $di = [DirectoryInfo]::new($destinationPath) 
    
    if ($di.Exists -or [Path]::EndsInDirectorySeparator($destinationPath)) { 
        throw [IOException] "DestinationPath cannot be a directory ($destinationPath)" 
    } 
    
    $fi = [FileInfo]::new($destinationPath)
    
    if ($fi.Exists) { 
        throw [IOException] "File already exists ($destinationPath)" 
    }
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Compress-CompatibleArchive

Command used in Test.ps1 file:
Compress-CompatibleArchive (args[1]) (args[2])

Arguments passed from cmdline :
./test1.ps1 "source path" "destination path"

I get the following error:
File not found (C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Pictures\testing)
At C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\modules\Compress-CompatibleArchive_Pranav.psm1:50 char:3
+         throw [FileNotFoundException] "File not found ($f)"
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : File not found (C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Pictures\testing)

Folder structure:
folder1
folder2
folder3 -1.txt, 2.txt


function ValidatePaths([String[]] $paths) {
foreach ($f in $paths) {
$fi = [FileInfo]::new($f);
if ($fi.Exists) {
continue;
}
throw [FileNotFoundException] "File not found ($f)"
}
}

function ValidateDestinationPath {
param ([String] $destinationPath)
$di = [DirectoryInfo]::new($destinationPath)
if ($di.Exists -or [Path]::EndsInDirectorySeparator($destinationPath)) {
throw [IOException] "DestinationPath cannot be a directory ($destinationPath)"
}
$fi = [FileInfo]::new($destinationPath);
if ($fi.Exists) {
throw [IOException] "File already exists ($destinationPath)"
}

Above are the 2 functions used to validate $Path and $DestinationPath

Why are you using this custom function to create your zip?

ValidatePaths throws because C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Pictures\testing is not a file path (it might be a directory - perhaps you'll want to use Test-Path instead?)

I assume the reason you're doing this is because ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory and Compress-Archive will stop processing when a file is in use by another process, if so, have a look at https://github.com/santisq/PSCompression/blob/main/docs/en-US/Compress-ZipArchive.md

because the zip gets converted into plugin file which doesnt work on .nix systems Santiago.

can you give an example of where can I use the Test-Path? Mathias
